# Timeout occurred from UserGroupInformation in yarn spark cluster

Tags: windows, apache-spark, timeout, hadoop-yarn

I structured Spark cluster. This cluster execute some heavy load UDF from spark-submit command. TimeoutException from `UserGroupInformation.doAs` method annoys me. My UDF always stop after 100 seconds. The following stacktrace got from "yarn logs" command. My environment is:`Spark-2.2.0`, `hadoop-2.7.1.2.4.0.0-169`, cluster PC number is 5. OS are Windows7/10 64bit(mixed). I aready tried to change spark.network.timeout setting, but it does not work... Is there any way to change this timeout?

```
    ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: 
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [100000 milliseconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:401)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:762)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
    INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 10, (reason: Uncaught exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [100000 milliseconds])
```

Comment: I could solve this issue.
I set 'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' to 'org.apache.spark.SparkConf' object.